# UIImageView stops displaying images after a specific amount of loop iterations

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

**My iOS app utilizes a loop to cycle through images in a folder.**
My application is supposed to loop through a total of 2031 images (sized 1200x900) inside a folder. The images were taken at 8fps and each image will be displayed as the loop continues to simulate a video clip.  After the 696th picture, the images will cease to be displayed in the UIImageView although the app will continue looping.

**I tested to see if the disconnect was because of the picture not existing**
I started the loop at picture 200, but after picture 896 the UIImageView stop displaying the pictures.

The Code:

```
imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"subject_basline_mat k (%d).png",jojo];
jojo++;
imageToCrop.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName]; //imageToCrop is the name of the UIImageView image and it is set to the image file here
imageToCrop.image = [self imageWithImage:imageToCrop.image convertToSize:self.imageToCrop.frame.size]; //Here the image is converted to fit the bounds of the simulator which is 320x240
```

The code loops due to a timer that loops it about once every 0.8 seconds.

I ran my code with instruments to see if there was a memory problem occurring,and instruments is very heavy on my computer.  As such, my application ran quite slowly.  However, when I arrived at the 696th picture, the pictures kept displaying themselves.  It was almost as if my application running too quickly caused the picture to not be displayed... which I don't really understand.

The only memory heavy part of the image switching seems to be the size conversion step which is called by the line imageToCrop.image = [self imageWithImage:imageToCrop.image convertToSize:self.imageToCrop.frame.size];

```
imageToCrop.image = [self imageWithImage:imageToCrop.image convertToSize:self.imageToCrop.frame.size];
```

The method "imageWithImage" is here:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image convertToSize:(CGSize)size {
@autoreleasepool {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return destImage;
}
```

And the line [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)]; uses around up the most memory out of all the image management in the app.

Any Ideas as to why my app will only display a certain amount of images?

Comment: If you downvote the question, please tell me why so that I can either improve the question or not post a question like this again. Thanks!

Comment: R u using ARC and make sure there is no Memory leak?

Comment: yes I am using ARC and there were no memory leaks as far as I saw when using instruments.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting that `0.8` second delay to see if it changes the number of images that will show? That could help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Yes. I tried that and the slower my program ran, the more pictures showed up.  However, for the purpose of what I'm working on, the application needs to run quickly.  So, I'm not sure why a slower program would do better with loading pictures than a fast one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the full-size images from the app bundle by URL. For example:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"subject_basline_mat k (%d)",jojo];
    NSURL *imageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:imgName withExtension:@"png"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageURL path]];
    imageToCrop.image = [self imageWithImage:image convertToSize:self.imageToCrop.frame.size];
}
```

Comment: yep that worked! didnt know that the images would be cached by the way I was doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Almost for sure your problem is `[UIImage imageNamed:imgName]`. There are hundreds of posts here on the pitfalls of using it. The issue is that it caches the images - its real purpose is for some small number of images in your bundle.

If you have oodles of images, get the path to the image, then get the image through a URL or file pointer. That way its not cached. Note that when you do this, you lose the automatic "get-retina-image-automatically", and so you will need to grab the appropriately sized image depending on whether the device is retina or not.